# iPhone can't voice some IPA notations taken from a dictionary

Tags: ios

It's possible to add a custom pronunciation to words on iOS by going to Settings -> Accessibility -> Spoken Content -> Pronunciations.

Here is the IPA notation for the pronunciation of the word "participation" taken from Wiktionary: `pɑɹˌtɪsɪˈpeɪʃən`. This does not work on iOS, but `pəɻ.ˈtɪ.sɪ.ˈpe͡ɪ.ʃən` works.

**Why is `pəɻ.ˈtɪ.sɪ.ˈpe͡ɪ.ʃən` voiced correctly but `pɑɹˌtɪsɪˈpeɪʃən` that is taken from a dictionary is not?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked to Apple support.

Comment: @Keelan I'm not sure if that's the case, but if it is, feel free to close the question. I was thinking that maybe these might be different types of IPA notations, or I thought maybe someone could explain the difference between the two notations, but if the only explanation why the first notation can't be properly voiced on iOS is "Because Apple made it so," I can understand why this question should be closed.

Comment: There are several differences between the two. You could try to give minimal pairs to figure out what iOS cannot handle exactly, if it isn’t documented.

Comment: dictionaries generally deviate from the official norms of the IPA. In this instance the dictionary isn't marking syllable boundaries or the non-syllabic off-glide of the diphthong. The other transcription you give also has some oddities. Diphthongs should be transcribed with the non-syllabic diacritic (e.g. `eɪ̯`) not with the tie (which is used for affricates and co-articulated consonants, giving the impression that the the e & ɪ are to be articulated simultaneously), and the use of əɻ in the first syllable would be non-standard

Comment: I suspect (but do not know) that the lack of explicit syllable boundaries is what's stopping the IPA > speech synthesiser from working, although the syllable with the diphthong may also be causing issues. Mostly I suspect it's that Apple requires a reasonably narrow transcription, whilst the wiktionary one is fairly broad. Do you get any audio at all out of the wiktionary pronunciation, and if so, could you provide the audio (mostly out of curiosity, I don't think it'd make this question on-topic on its own)?

Comment: @Tristan You can listen to them here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1y9o0a2ojwi326d/AAAaQEiOeW8dcDBhjyOkToJJa?dl=0. ios-1 is completely wrong and ios-2 is pronounced correctly. If you paste the notations I provided to http://ipa-reader.xyz (which uses Amazon Polly) they are both voiced correctly.

Comment: yeah, my money's on the lack of explicit syllable boundaries. If you add the `.` in to the wiktionary transcription at the appropriate places do you get something more sensible?

Comment: An alternative to asking Apple support is [apple.se]

Comment: It is well understood that the IPA does not dictate the phonological analysis of a language, does not deterministically force a single symbol choice in intermediate cases (where a vowel is somewhere between three or four standard vowels), and of course relies entirely on acoustic inputs rather than orthography. You don't say what you mean by "doesn't work" (produces nothing at all? does not produce what you want?); but this is an Apple problem, not a linguistic problem.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that they intend the product to be a general-purpose IPA synthesizer capable of outputting Zulu and Arabic as well?

Comment: @user6726 You can listen to the sound samples I provided in the comments to see what I mean with "doesn't work". I don't have any evidence that they intend the product to be a general-purpose IPA synthesizer, nor did I claim I was under the impression that they did. I'm just developing a dictionary app and I was just curious if I could just use iOS's own synthesizer to provide sample pronunciations based on IPA notations on Wiktionary.

Comment: @Tristan It, unfortunately, didn't work with syllable boundaries either, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @EvrimPersembe in that case this is an odd bug/the synthesizer relies on its own (somewhat idiosyncratic) transcription. If you can find documentation of it you may be able to programmatically convert wiktionary's transcriptions into something apple will accept, but it's hard to say. Contacting their support and looking for any docs they provide will likely be the next step